# remove session after 10 hours of activity in my asp.net web site

Tags: asp.net, .net, ajax, session, timer

I need to remove session after 10 hours of user activity.

My question is about counting the 10 hours.

I tried to use ajax Timer (asp.net) with updatepanel. I put it in the master page but switch between pages reset the timer. So I tried this idea:
[Asp.net Timer resets on page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34491996/asp-net-timer-resets-on-page-refresh?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)
but it causes page load every second.

What is the best way to count time user is active in the site?

Is it a good way to use this timer or there is better one ?

Or alternatively Is there a better way to reset session (like session timeout) despite of user activity?

Answer (score 0):

Set Session Timeout in Web.Config ASP.Net will handle itself

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState 
      mode="InProc"
      cookieless="true"
      timeout="600" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

You can refer for more here:
http://www.primaryobjects.com/2008/01/29/preventing-session-timeouts-in-c-asp-net-web-applications/

To find active user, you can use performance counter on the server:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fxk122b4.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to add in Global.asax

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["SessionExpiry"] = DateTime.Now.AddHours(10);
}

void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  try
  {
      DateTime expiry = (DateTime)base.Context.Session["SessionExpiry"];

      if (expiry <= DateTime.Now)
      {
          Session.Abandon();

          // the abandoned session won't kick in until the next page request.
          // here I am redirecting back to the current page, but you may want to do something else
          // like redirect to a "Session Expired" page.
          Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
          base.Context.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
      }
  }
  catch
  {
  }
}
```

Source:
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1175605/How-to-timeout-session-in-minutes-in-ASP-NET